# Build Netdata deb package for Ubuntu16

Tags: packaging, deb, netdata

I need to build a Netdata deb package for Ubuntu16 and I'm getting some troubles. I'm using fpm-cookery to try to build it but it is difficult to analyze how many things have to configure. Do you know any recipe and/or some other tool to build it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netdata finally created the deb packages for Ubuntu 16 so I dont need to create it by myself anymore:

https://packagecloud.io/app/netdata/netdata/search?q=&filter=debs&filter=all&dist=ubuntu%2Fxenial